# Installed 'Microsoft VS code' in custom directory now I can't use Go support

Tags: visual-studio, go

I've installed Microsoft VS Code in another partition (Drive D) on my Windows 10 system. I prefer to keep Microsoft VS Code in another partition away from Windows.

My goal is to install the GO extension from Microsoft. The link to the extension is here.

[Click here to visit the source of the repository to the go extension.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go.git)

The following error occurs when I attempt to install the GO extension through the Extension dialog in the Microsoft VS Code application.

The Error:

> Failed to run "go env" to find GOPATH as the "go" binary cannot be
> found in either GOROOT(undefined) or PATH (
>
> C:\Windows\system32;
>
> C:\Windows;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
>
> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;
>
> **a gfx card driver directory here**;
>
> **a gfx card driver directory here**;
>
> C:\Users\ **My username left out**
> \AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
>
> )

I suspect that the cause is the fact that I installed Microsoft VS Code in another partition. I've also mentioned this at the beginning of my question. I've explained the steps that I took to find the solution below:

First I examined the location of the go resource. It seems that my resource is placed in the right folder (the folder of my installation.

> D:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\go

Than I tried a simple command through the commands by pressing **`ctrl+shift+p`** and then typing go:Current GOPATH. the error message

> command go.goroot not found

Then I thought of testing out if I can run a basic go file. I searched for a simple example and came across [this site.](https://gobyexample.com/hello-world). So, I've created a project folder and added the file Hello.go in the folder **D:\VS_Projects\GO_Helloworld** Then I placed the hello world program in it. The program is shown below

```
package main


import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

In the microsoft vs code powershell terminal I check if the terminal is in the right folder. It shows 'PS D:\VS_Projects\GO_Helloworld>' so that should be right. I run the following command:

```
go run Hello.go
```

The following error is shown in the terminal:

> on, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name
> , or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> again.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - go run Hello.go
> - ~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (go:String) [], Comma      ndNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I'm currently thinking of steps to take as described by ['ramya-rao-a'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595#issuecomment-517076042) and ['AndreiD'](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595#issuecomment-520515437) on [this github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2595) in the powershell terminal.

My first thought was posting my question here first.

> Edit: Since I posted this thread, I've updated this question because it was marked as 'off-topic' Due to a mispronounciation of 'Microsoft VS Code'. I mistakenly use 'Microsoft' and that's a very broad term obviously.
> I disclose the private feedback here.
>
> "We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software
> on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for
> Stack Overflow or post a new one on Super User".
>
> [I've posted this question on super user.](https://superuser.com/questions/1516463/installed-microsoft-vs-code-in-custom-directory-now-i-cant-use-go-support) I'll leave this post here so that other users see my post as an **almost** off-topic example.

Let me know if you have an answer to my problem **[on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/1516463/installed-microsoft-vs-code-in-custom-directory-now-i-cant-use-go-support)**. Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That was an obvious mistake I overlooked. It's always in my best interest to be 'on-topic'. So I've corrected my question. Im looking forward to hear from you soon!

Comment: In the meantime I'll look for other ways to find simlar problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer can be found on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1516466/1129007). Also, I like to clearify why my post was originally closed according to [the guidelines of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I Quote:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

I'm not sure to why the user who spotted the mistake removed his comment.

> He said: What do you mean by 'Microsoft'?

It was helpful though. Anyway, I'll close this post now.